# How to fix MassTransit.EndpointNotFoundException when using Request/Response initialized with localhost?

Tags: c#, masstransit

We are using masstransit with Request/Response pattern as described here: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/request-response.html

For some reason when the bus is initialized with localhost I receive a MassTransit.EndpointNotFoundException on the respond side, using context.RespondAsync method.

When the bus is initialized with the actual IP it works good without any exception.

We are using the bus also with other patterns of masstransit initialized with localhost without any problems.

We tried using both, Request and GetResponse patterns on the request side thinking maybe the problem source is there, but with no success.

Following is the consumer code the Response side, which generate the exception on the RespondAsync:

```
public override async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IImageRequest> context)
{
    var msg = context.Message;

    try
    {    
        var image = GetImage(msg.Id);

        await context.RespondAsync<IImageResult>(new
        {
            msg.Id,
            AImage = image
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Instance.Error($"{e}");
    }
}
```

Following is the request side:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{   
    var reqResClient =
        BusControl.GetBusControl.CreateRequestClient<IImageRequest, IImageResult>("requestimage");
    var req = new ImageRequest(msg.Id);
    var response = await reqResClient.Request(req); 
}).Wait();
```

Bus initialization code:

```
_bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Durable = true;

    _host = cfg.Host(HostName, port, VirtualHost, h =>
    {
        h.Username(UserName);
        h.Password(Password);   
    });

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, subscriber.QueueName, ep =>
    {
        ep.Durable = !subscriber.AutoDelete;
        ep.AutoDelete = subscriber.AutoDelete;

        ep.Instance(subscriber.Consumer);

        if (subscriber.PrefetchCount.HasValue)
            ep.PrefetchCount = subscriber.PrefetchCount.Value;

        if (subscriber.ConcurrencyLimit.HasValue)
            ep.UseConcurrencyLimit(subscriber.ConcurrencyLimit.Value);
    });

    cfg.Message<T>(x =>
    {
        x.SetEntityName(entityName);
    });
});
```

```
public void Start()
{
    if (_state == BusState.NotInitialized)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot start bus. Bus is not initialized");

    _bus?.Start();

    _state = BusState.Started;
}
```

I wanted to know if there's a solution for it? or is it a known problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Local Host is defined in file : C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.  On some machine it is set to an IP address and on other it is set to loopback 127.0.0.1.  You could edit the file.  The net library usually give an error if you try to connect to the address.  The problem may be with the Server.  The server should use the machine IP address.  Instead the Server should listen to IP.Any.  The server and client cannot use the same IP address and the same port.  So normally you make the server IP.Any so it is different from the client when server and listener are on same machine.

Comment: On the request side, what is the bus initialisation code? You must have the bus configured and started for the whole application lifecycle to use MassTransit.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev thanks - added the initialization code.

Comment: @jdweng thanks - the host file is the default file (everything is remarked) - localhost is not defined.

Comment: @YuvalBechor what is the `subscriber`? Where do you start the bus?

Comment: What is the ResponseAddress of the message in the consumer, which is sent by the request client? If it's coming from a different machine, using localhost can be problematic.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev added the start method. The subscriber is an object with all the information of the subscriber. subscriber.Consumer - holds the consumer object.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson the request client and response server is on different machines. The request client is initialized with the server IP and the response server with localhost.

Comment: yeah, you might need to use the same, although there was a fix to make it work a long time ago. If you're hard-coding an IP address, might as well use it both places.

Comment: What do you get from cmd.exe with following : >Ping localhost

Comment: @jdweng thanks - I get from pinging localhost four replies 4 sent 4 received and 0  lost, all are less than 1ms.

Comment: Does Computer Name match your PC?  If you are using DCHP the IP address of computer changes (usually once a month but can be different).  So when ever you use DCHP you should use the Computer Name and not IP so it always works.

Comment: This for reference was closed without making a change to support what you're asking for because it can't be assumed. https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/542

Comment: So, I just tested this using an IP address and localhost on another, and it works just fine for me with RabbitMQ. What version of MassTransit are you using?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson we are using MassTransit version 5.1.5

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I am curious to try your code snippet here, it would be a tremendous help if it works (because we are using also other masstransit consumers with different patterns all initialized with localhost from the same config).  Thanks.